# Tyre sidewall chipped

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

Hi I have damaged my tyre wall by hitting car park kerb.
Would I need to replace whole tyre?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The sidewall of a tire takes a lot of load and stress. It is an important part of the tire.

From what I see in that picture, it looks pretty deep. So, yes, it should be replaced for safety reasons.

Not changing it risks blowout while driving which can cause an accident and/or injury.

Answer (score 1):

That needs replacing, even if the damage does not reach the plies, it has stressed that area...

That type of damage on the sidewall cannot be repaired so you need to get it replaced, in fact, I suggest you fit the spare and have it replaced as soon as ...